# Image Scan for Epson v500 photo works for flatbed but not for TPU on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: drivers, scanner, epson

I downloaded and installed Image Scan(iscan-gt-x770-bundle-2.30.4.x64.deb) for linux from the Epson website and the flatbed of the scanner is working fine, but whenever I attempt to scan or preview with TPU, it times out and gives me the following error:

```
Could not send command to scanner. Check the scanner's status.
```

Afterwards the light on the scanner starts to blink orange.

Simple scan works with the "front" option, but "back" and "both" return the same image that "front" does, without raising any errors. Has anyone else had this error? How can I start troubleshooting?

Additionally, I've tried scanning with VueScan with only success on the flatbed. I don't think it's a hardware issue since the TPU light lights up when I send the command to scan, but it only moves a few cm before it stops and the status light starts blinking orange.